# SQL Server cell level encryption: preventing DBA from seeing the data

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to prevent DBAs in ops team from looking at cell level encrypted data.

Is it possible in SQL Server to do this:

a. Delegate cryptographic key management functionality to one person (security PM) and revoke all access to data for him.
b. Remove cryptographic key management & access functionality from system administrator.

By doing this, unless the two colluded they cannot see the data.

Comment: Why, oh why, would you want to prevent your DBA from looking at data.  If there is one person you *need* to trust, its your DBA.

Comment: It is ironic that the requirement itself comes from Ops management:) Tried enough to push back. Now I need to find if it is possible or not.

Comment: To that I would say: "if the DBA has sa access, he can access the system.  If he doesn't have sa access, he's not a DBA".  Oh, and I feel your pain.

Comment: Most people, when they say "DBA", assume sysadmin access. In this case, there is no protection from DBA. If you don't trust them, it's better to fire them. It is possible to prevent persons with any level of access from seeing the data, if that data was encrypted with asymmetric algorithms and the corresponding private key is out of reach. But that will require a serious redesign of the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enterprise Edition that is 2008R2 or above, then what you need is an Extensible Key Management system. The exact function of an EKM is that which you described. The Hardware Security Module of the EKM will contain keys and algorithms and will perform the encryption and decryption functions. The SQL Server will only contain the encrypted data. Management of the EKM can be delegated to your Security PM. An EKM should be transparent to the application.

SQL Server 2016 also has a feature called Always Encrypted. This puts the encryption key in the client driver and separates it from the server.